# AUTOINCREMENT and order of arguments in INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

Tags: sqlite, syntax, primary-key, auto-increment

In SQLite, the following works:

```
CREATE TABLE "b" (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL);
```

but the following throws an error:

```
CREATE TABLE "c" (id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);
```

the error being:

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error
At line 6:
CREATE TABLE "c" (id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT
```

Why changing the order of the arguments throws a syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/column-constraint.html), in SQLite AUTOINCREMENT must go after PRIMARY KEY.